# shear force on a cube

Tags: animation

im very new to blender. how can i animate this cube, just the cube, like on the video? where the right and left face got pulled up and down. i want to show how shear force act on the cube for a video that im making. thank you very much for your help

[image]

Comment: Does it need to be a physic simulation? If not you could simply hook the left and right faces of the cube

Comment: Another option is Shape Keys. This allows you to set different shapes of the mesh in Edit mode and then blend between them.